# Cost doesn't converge on tensorflow regression- python

Tags: tensorflow

I just recently learned tensorflow. I tried to run a simple regression example, but I got a bad result.

My input X is a matrix of 10x10000, that is, each data is a vector of 10x1, a total of 10000 pieces of data.

Desired output Y is just first row of X.

My code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import RandomState
rdm=RandomState(1)
data_size=10000
xdim=10
X=rdm.rand(data_size,xdim)
Y = [x1[0] for x1 in X]

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,xdim))
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None))
#logits = modelFun(x)
Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([xdim, 1]))
biases = tf.Variable(0.1)
logits = tf.matmul(x, Weights) + biases
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(logits - y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.005).minimize(loss)

batch_size=50
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    steps=20001
    for i in range(steps):
        start = i * batch_size % data_size
        end = min(start + batch_size,data_size)
        sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x:X[start:end],y:Y[start:end]})
        if i % 5000 == 0:
            ypred,training_loss= sess.run([logits,loss],feed_dict={x:X,y:Y})
            print("Epoch %d: loss=%g"%(i,training_loss))
```

The output results are as follows:

```
Epoch 0: loss=6.31555
Epoch 5000: loss=0.0798763
Epoch 10000: loss=0.0797333
Epoch 15000: loss=0.0797259
Epoch 20000: loss=0.079724
```

It can't go down to 0.0797.
I checked part of the output. They are far from the correct answer.

```
>>>print(ypred[:10].T[0])
[ 0.49342471  0.49475971  0.50192004  0.48912409  0.50592101  0.48473218   0.48652697  0.50261581  0.50218904  0.48906678]

>>>print(np.array(Y[:10]))
[ 0.417022    0.41919451  0.80074457  0.09834683  0.98886109  0.01936696  0.10233443  0.90340192  0.88330609  0.11474597]
```

What is the reason for this? How to solve it?
So thanks for your help!

Comment: There are lots of questions asking "why won't my neural network training converge?" on Stack Overflow, and they are almost always too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for too much from your model.  You're generating 10000 points of ten-dimensional random data, so there's no structure to learn, and then doing linear regression with a single neuron; your model doesn't have the capacity to even begin to memorize your input, so guessing that every `y` is about 0.5 is the best it can do.

The biggest issue is the random input.  Most types of machine learning models make strong assumptions about the structure of what they're trying to learn, and random data doesn't have that structure.  A large enough neural network could memorize you input data and give you a low training error, but it would completely fail to generalize (the test error would be high), and generalizing is usually the goal.